# PackageManager doesn't recognize inner inten-filter

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, android-library, intentfilter

I have an android app that triggers an intent.
It depended on an android lib that defines an intent-filter in its androidManifest to catch this intent.

```
 <application>
    <activity
        android:name="myCode.InternalDummyActivity"
        android:exported="false">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="myIntent.action"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>
```

> one app triggers the intent, and the handling activity is defined
>   in an android library

However, in the android app code the `packageManager` doesn't recognize an app that can handle this intent.

```
  Intent intent = new Intent();
 intent.setAction("myIntent.action");
```

...

```
List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfos = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent,0);
```

`resolveInfos` has 0 items.

What can i be missing?

I have tried `android:exported =` `true` and `false`

Comment: How are you constructing `intent`?

Comment: added the code for that

Comment: Is the code calling `queryIntentActivities()` in the same app as `myCode.InternalDummyActivity`? Or is it in some other app?

Comment: one app triggers the intent, and the handling activity is defined in an android library

Comment: That did not really answer my question. How many *apps* are we talking about here? Is there one app, or two?

Comment: I have tried one app with this library. For simple case. But Eventually I want to simulate 2 apps that use similar android library that contains the handling activity